# String Interpolation error

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have defined one variable:

```
var photosArray: [String: [String]] = [:]
```

Then, I iterated over NSDictionary, i get these values:

```
let recipenameString = recipename as! String
let indexString = index as! String
let leftsideString = leftside as! String
let rightsideString = rightside as! String
```

Now, the problem is:

```
var firstString = "\(recipenameString) \(indexString)"
let secondString = ["\(leftsideString)", "\(rightsideString)"]
photosArray[firstString : secondString]
```

I get this compiler error, cant figure out what is wrong with the string interpolation:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String]]' with an index of type '(firstString: [String])'
```

Any ideas? 
Thank you.

Comment: you have a `Dictionary` that store an `Array of String` as value, so you should have something like `photos["firstkey"] = [firstString, SecondString] ` or `photos = ["firstkey": [firstString, SecondString ], "secondKey": [thirdString, fourthString] ]` so on

Answer (score 0):

You have a dictionary but treating it as a array: 
Try this:

```
var firstString = recipenameString  + indexString 
var stringArray = [leftSideString, rightSideString]

photosArray[firstString] = stringArray
```

This should do it

and this will help too: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html